# npm install needs authentication in VSTS hosted build

Tags: npm, npm-install, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

In  Visual Studio Team Services, I am trying to run npm install on a hosted build server prior to my solution getting built.  But access to our  https://our_url.visualstudio.com/GIT is being denied:

> npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\NPM\Cache_git-remotes_templates
>   --mirror https://our_url.visualstudio.com/GIT/_git/our_url-gulp-bundle-helper
>   C:\NPM\Cache_git-remotes\git-https-our_url-visualstudio-com-GIT-git-our_url-gulp-bundle-helper-2-2-7-88eb446d:
>   Cloning into bare repository
>   'C:\NPM\Cache_git-remotes\git-https-our_url-visualstudio-com-GIT-git-our_url-gulp-bundle-helper-2-2-7-88eb446d'...
>
> npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\NPM\Cache_git-remotes_templates
>   --mirror https://our_url.visualstudio.com/GIT/_git/our_url-gulp-bundle-helper
>   C:\NPM\Cache_git-remotes\git-https-our_url-visualstudio-com-GIT-git-our_url-gulp-bundle-helper-2-2-7-88eb446d:
>   Fatal: InvalidOperationException encountered.
>
> npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\NPM\Cache_git-remotes_templates
>   --mirror https://our_url.visualstudio.com/GIT/_git/our_url-gulp-bundle-helper
>   C:\NPM\Cache_git-remotes\git-https-our_url-visualstudio-com-GIT-git-our_url-gulp-bundle-helper-2-2-7-88eb446d:
>   fatal: Authentication failed for
>   'https://our_url.visualstudio.com/GIT/_git/our_url-gulp-bundle-helper/'
>
> npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\NPM\Cache_git-remotes_templates
>   --mirror https://our_url.visualstudio.com/GIT/_git/our_url-gulp-bundle-helper
>   C:\NPM\Cache_git-remotes\git-https-our_url-visualstudio-com-GIT-git-our_url-gulp-bundle-helper-2-2-7-88eb446d:
>   fatal: Authentication failed for
>   'https://our_url.visualstudio.com/GIT/_git/our_url-gulp-bundle-helper/'

It appears it's simply our access being denied, which I thought I was fixing by going into GIT and adding the '*Project Collection Build Service Accounts*' to the team permissions, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.  Any idea what i need to do to get the hosted build server to have permissions to our GIT server?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to set up my [personal access token](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate) and pass it through with my package.json:

```
"my_package": git+https://my-name%40my-domain.com:[TOKEN]@my_url.visualstudio.com/GIT/_git/my_package#2.2.7
```